# How to use a_timedelta.total_seconds() to create a countdown timer that breaks when below 0?

Tags: python, datetime

```
import time,datetime
end_game = False
count=0
timer=10
date_and_time1 = datetime.datetime.now()
while True:
        if end_game == True:
          break
        choice3 = input("Break the clock.")
        
        if count == 4:
              print("YOU ARE OUT OF DEBT!")
              true = False
              break
        else:
              if choice3 == "break":
                date_and_time2 = datetime.datetime.now()
                a_timedelta = date_and_time2 - date_and_time1
                seconds = a_timedelta.total_seconds()
                if seconds <= 0:
                  print("You did not break the clock fast enough...")
                  time.sleep(2)
                  print("You lose.")
                  end_game = True
                elif seconds > 0:
                  count += 1
                  print(timer - seconds, " seconds left")
              else:
                print("The timer is running out. ('break')")
```

I am quite new to python. I am trying to create a timed mini game as part of a larger program where the user simply has to type 'break' 5x within 10 seconds in order to win. At the moment, when the timer runs out (seconds < 0), the loop does not break as it should. Is there a simple way to fix this?

Comment: first of you can simply use `while not end_game:`, that is what `while` loops are for, they iterate while the condition is met. second, if you have `input`, the code stops there and waits for input, doesn't do anything else, if you want to do something concurrently, then you need to use [`threading`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html)

Comment: but also given that it is `input` it is not going to be easy to "kill" it (killing threads in general is not simple, for that though `multiprocessing` could be used), a better approach would be to use a GUI instead, also don't import modules in one line and also you don't need `datetime` for a countdown timer